Solana Rust Hello World Build fails with 'cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer' error
I've been working through this example: https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/local-rust-hello-world
Build when I attempt to build using cargo build-bpf I get the following error:
error: package `solana-program v1.18.9` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.72.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.75.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.9 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `solana-program` supporting rustc 1.72.0-dev

Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "hello_world"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"


# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
solana-program = "1.18.9"
solana-sdk = "1.18.9"

And:
rustc --version
rustc 1.77.1 (7cf61ebde 2024-03-27)
rustup --version
rustup 1.27.0 (bbb9276d2 2024-03-08)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.77.1 (7cf61ebde 2024-03-27)`

cargo --version
cargo 1.77.1 (e52e36006 2024-03-26)

cargo-build-sbf --version
solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.18.1
platform-tools v1.39
rustc 1.72.0

I just got my environment setup and not sure what I'm missing..

Please modify your Cargo.toml dependencies:
[dependencies]
...
solana-program = "=1.18.2"

solana-program 1.18.2 is compatible with your Rust version.
Hint: To find out which Rust version is used by anchor, run cargo-build-sbf --version.

I changed the version as you suggested and Gott the same error.
Also
cargo-build-sbf --version
solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.18.1
platform-tools v1.39
rustc 1.72.0

Be sure to upgrade to the newest CLI tools as well by running:
solana-install init 1.18.9

That will give you a newer Rust compiler for Solana programs:
$ solana --version
solana-cli 1.18.9 (src:9a7dd9ca; feat:3469865029, client:SolanaLabs)
$ cargo build-sbf --version
solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.18.9
platform-tools v1.41
rustc 1.75.0


cargo build-sbf --version seems stuck at previous version. Any cache I need to remove?

Maybe, you can check for the cached platform tools in ls ~/.cache/solana/

Upgraded Solana library and this resolved the error.

This worked for me.
solana-install update


If you're on macos, make sure your rust is downloaded natively and not from homebrew!
Don't doubt it's the version of solana-install, go to https://crates.io/crates/solana-install/versions and check the latest version, for example it's currently 1.18.18, then solana-install init 1.18.18, and then it's Then you can continue to anchor build :)

This command worked for me:
solana-install init 1.18.9

