Anchor Test fails with version error
Issue:
I installed everything needed to start developing on Solana.
I am trying to test a simple contract but when i run: anchor test, it errors out the following:
error: package `solana-program v1.18.11` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.72.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.75.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.11 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `solana-program` supporting rustc 1.72.0-dev

I tried fixing it in every possible way but this problem is persistent.
I got version 1.77 installed.
Did anyone encounter this before?
Hardware:
Apple Macbook Air M2

Hey, does this help your problem? https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/12517/solana-rust-hello-world-build-error

Yes this was it!
Thank you very much that was the thing that i overlooked.
Added it to the toml file and it works fine now.
Have to get used to the whole rust stuff.
