cargo build-bpf doesnt work
and error message is
error: package solana-program v1.18.11 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.72.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.75.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.11 --precise ver
where ver is the latest version of solana-program supporting rustc
1.72.0-dev
error message seems i didnt update my rustc version.
but i already update my rustc.
what happened!!


Does this answer your question? Solana Rust Hello World Build fails with 'cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer' error

Does this help? https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/12517/solana-rust-hello-world-build-fails-with-cannot-be-built-because-it-requires-ru
